# Lazy image load and unload

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, memory-consumption

I have a big collection of large images that I need to process.

It would be nice if an image was lazy loaded (`Lazy class`) and destroyed when processed.

However what is missing in `Lazy<>` class is reset event that disposes initialized object and enables to  load an object again (to save memory).

It would be nice if the lazy method had `Clone()` or `Reset()` method.

Is there any structure that can do that (or I have to write on my own) ?

Comment: is it winforms? wpf? or web? (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) for desktop (winforms, wpf) you can load async

Comment: Can't you just dispose the `lazy.Value` and create a new `Lazy<T>`? I guess the factory func will be different for a new value, right?

Comment: Neither. It is not platform specific. Yes I can dispose the Lazy<> but I can not load it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispose of a lazy's value quite easily.

```
if (lazy.IsValueCreated) 
    lazy.Value.Dispose();
```

assuming `Lazy<T>` where `T` is `IDisposable`.

I'm not sure why you would want to allow it to create an image again because you will get the same image back. If you want a different image, create a new `Lazy<T>` with a different factory delegate.

Comment: Yes, I want the same image back. But there are so many images that I can not hold them as collection (e.g. List<>), so I have to incrementally load and unload them.

Comment: I think you're asking for a cache, then, rather than lazy-loading. You should look at one of the [.NET caching classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.objectcache.aspx), but they don't behave in the same way as `Lazy`.